# How to count the same name inside a column?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, ms-access, oledb

This is my column showing the name of the president the user voted:

[image: snapshot]

I need to count these names in order to show the result of the election. How do I count it using select `count()` and group by?

Comment: Post your link in your question in its entirety.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Show what you did and explain how it does nto satisfy you. Avoid the impression of looking for a free coding service. Please take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following SQL should do the trick.

```
SELECT President, COUNT(*)
FROM tbl_voter
GROUP BY President
```

Comment: how do I put that in a commandtext? `command.commandText = " Select President, Count(*) from tbl_voter group by President";` will this work?

Answer (score 0):

Select v.President, count(v.President) from tbl_voter v group by v.President;

You need put on count function the name of column you want to count and use the group by in the same column.

Comment: i'll try this one

Comment: now how do I put that selected data inside a listbox?

Comment: It depends wich languange you're using

Comment: I am using c# with access database and oledb

Comment: Sorry, but C# i don't now how to do this, open another question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use LINQ for this, you need to have an IQueryable for your records. After that it is easy:

```
IQueryable<VotingRecord> votingRecords = ...
votingRecords.GroupBy(votingRecord => votingRecord.President)
.Select(presidentGroup => new
{
    President = presidentGroup.Key,
    VoteCount = presidentGroup.Count(),
});
```

`GroupBy` will make groups of `VotingRecords` that voted for the same president. The `Key` of the group is the name of the president. All `VotingRecords` in the group voted for this `Key` president.

The `Select` takes each group, and from each group it takes the `Key`, which is the President, and the number of VotingRecords in this group, which is the number of votes for the president.

Result is a sequence of records with `Presidents` and the numbers of votes for this president.

By the way, let's hope that proper democracies won't implement this database, because this way it would be easy to find out who voted for whom.